# postgresql: ident authentication failed on fedora

Tags: postgresql, fedora, postgresql-9.6, fedora-27

I know this question has been asked several times before, but all answers I could find tell you to add a line like the following to the `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5
```

So my `pg_hba.conf` file now looks like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD                                                                                                                                             

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only                                                                                                                                                               
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:                                                                                                                                                                                          
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:                                                                                                                                                                                          
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the                                                                                                                                                 
# replication privilege.                                                                                                                                                                                           
#local   replication     postgres                                peer                                                                                                                                              
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident                                                                                                                                             
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident                                                                                                                                             

# I've added the following lines:
host    all             all              127.0.0.1/32           trust
host    all             all              ::1/128                trust
host    all             all              127.0.0.1/32           md5
host    all             all              ::1/128                md5
host    all             all              192.168.0.0/24         md5
```

I have set up several postgresql servers in the past on ubuntu and never had a problem. However, on fedora, I still get the following error message:

```
FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

The server is running on Fedora 27 Workstation and the postgresql version is *9.6.8-1.fc27*.

Comment: hey, did you reload the conf file? `select pg_reload_conf();` I mean, if you cannot afford restarting the database system.

Comment: @JimJones I did a `systemctl restart postgresql` several times

Comment: Just to test, if you change `ident` to `trust`, do you manage to connect?

Comment: just comment that line `host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident` and leave this one  as it is `host    all             all              127.0.0.1/32           trust`

Comment: @JimJones Thanks! That seems to be the trick. Why can't I have both `ident` and `trust` enabled?

Comment: My first guess would be that it tries to verify both options, making `trust` in this case being overwritten by `ident`. Would you mind if I put this solution into an answer, so that other users find it too?

Comment: @JimJones Yes please do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two authentication rules for localhost in your `pg_hba.conf`, namely ..

```
host all  all  127.0.0.1/32  ident
```

and

```
host all  all  127.0.0.1/32  trust
```

I believe the system is trying to validate the two authentication options, making the `trust` option being overwritten by `ident`. Since you're most likely trying to use `trust` to authenticate from localhost (based on your file), just comment/delete the following line:

```
host all  all  127.0.0.1/32  ident
```

And afterwards either restart your database or reload the conf file using the following query:

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```